# How to read previous lines in Python relative to a search found in the log file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logfile, readlines

I am a newbie to Python so just trying things with it.
I have a huge file , where after searching for a search phrase ,I should go back by n lines and get the start of the text, start tag .
After that start reading from that position .

The phrases can occur multiple times . And there are multiple start tags.
 Please find the sample file as below:

```
<module>
hi
flowers
<name>xxx</name>
<age>46</age>
</module>
<module>
<place>yyyy</place>
<name>janiiiii</janii>
</module>
```

Assume the search is  , and I need to go back to the line  once I search the . The lines between & will vary , they are not static. So once I find the name I need to go back to the module line and start reading it .

Please find the below code:

```
from itertools import islice
lastiterline=none
line_num=0
search_phrase="Janiii"
with open ('c:\sample.txt',"rb+") as f:
      for line in f:
          line_num+=1
     line=line.strip()
        if line.startswith("<module>"):
           lastiterline=line
           linec=line_num
        elif line find(search_phrase)>=0:
             if lastiterline:
             print line
             print linec
```

This helps me to get the line number of the module corresponding to the word searched.But I am unable to move back the pointer to start reading the lines again from module. There will be multiple search phrases, So everytime I need to go back to that line without breaking the main for, which reads the entire huge file.

For eg :there may be 100 modules tags , and inside that I might have 10 search phrases which I want , so I just need those 10 module tags .

Comment: provide your code for searching inside the file

Comment: can u provide even an example of the file, maybe 3-4 lines to show us how is structured and what you are trying to archive pls?

Comment: Have updated it now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is an example for you, so you can be more specific with what you need.

This is a sample of your `huge_file.txt`:

```
wgoi jowijg
<start tag>
wfejoije jfie
fwjoejo
THE PHRASE
jwieo
<end tag>
wjefoiw wgworjg
<start tag>
wjgoirg 
<end tag>
<start tag>
wfejoije jfie
fwjoejo
woeoj
jwieo
THE PHRASE
<end tag>
```

And a script `read_prev_lines.py`:

```
hugefile = open("huge_file.txt", "r")
hugefile = hugefile.readlines()

start_locations = []
current_block = -1
for idx, line in enumerate(hugefile):
  if "<start tag>" in line:
    start_locations.append({"start": idx})
    current_block += 1
  if "THE PHRASE" in line:
    start_locations[current_block]["phr"] = idx
  if "<end tag>" in line:
    start_locations[current_block]["end"] = idx

#for i in phrase_locations:
for idx in range(len(start_locations)):
  if "phr" in start_locations[idx].keys():
    print("Found THE PHRASE after %d start tag(s), at line %d:" % (idx, start_locations[idx]["phr"]))
    print("Here is the whole block that contains the phrase:")
    print(hugefile[start_locations[idx]["start"]: start_locations[idx]["end"]+1])
```

Comment: Thanks dsalaj. But the problem is n is not static , that is not defined .It varies for every other search. So need to check how that works

Comment: That is no problem. Just provide the description of how you need the `n` to be calculated. Do you need all the lines between target phrase and the start token with variable lengths of lines in between? Or something else?

Comment: @karthikasai I have updated the answer to work with dynamic `n` based on the start tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dsalaj .let me try this out

Comment: Dsalaj : The prob here is if the phrase is available only in the second start tag , it starts printing from the first .I want it only for the second alone.

Comment: @karthikasai I updated the answer and input file to match the described behavior you seek. Now it ignores the empty blocks without the phrase. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot . is it possible to print the entire block ?

The phrase is in between the tags start and end , so wherever the phrase occurs will we print it from the start to end?? @Dsalaj

Comment: The whole aim is to create anew text file for every other occurrence of the phrase and write the contents there. So if we have 20 blocks with 10 occurrences so from start to end I will create  a text file for every occurence and put it over there.

Comment: @karthikasai That's easy. You just additionally store the index of end tag (just like for the phrase) and then create a list with those indices. See the updates solution for the code. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your question.